# Spring MVC set attribute to response/model/modelMap via Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I would like to set some attributes to my session or modelAttribute in my page using Ajax, those values are needed to do some information proccesing later.

Without Ajax I was able to do this using:

```
 model.addAttribute("currentComponent", "system.fileUpload");
 model.addAttribute("status", uploadStatus);
 model.addAttribute("prueba",generatedFile);
 model.addAttribute("path", rutaLiquidacionesNetas);
 model.addAttribute("dateFolder", dateAndTimeFolder);
 return "file/upload";
```

I setted those values and then in my JSP I was able to access them but now using Ajax I cant get those values because they are not even being setted.

Here is my ajax function:

```
$("#load-file").click(function(){
        var sappUrl = $("#uploadForm").attr( "action") + "/generateFile";
        var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("uploadForm"));

       $.ajax({
            url: sappUrl,
            data: formData,
            type: "POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {           
                $("#results-files").html(data);         
            },
            error: function() { $("#result").html("Ha ocurrido un pelon"); }
        });             
    });
```

I hope somebody could help me because I´ve only found examples about setting attributes to the request

Comment: What you need now is json approach. Instead put values in model attribute just make json. Take a look into `gson` or whatever framework you like. You need to remember that your `controller` method need to produce json format.

Comment: Good, I'll take a look. Right now my controller is returning just a String with the information took from a file. With this gson thing (never used it) can I get not only the information but the name and so many information as I want?

Comment: Something important to mention... Can I use another approach which does not required a libreary that has to be downloaded? I can't add any other library by now, dont ask, requierements :/